# Combine Excel value into new content

Tags: excel

I am writing content for products and want to use Excel to compile the data into one cell. The data can integrate HTML tags

Cell value example of what I am looking to accomplish below. How to I get the data to pull into the new cell ?

Title
=A1
Description
=B2
Compatible Models
=C2
Shipping
=D2
Returns
=E2
Warranty information
=F2

Comment: May be you are looking for [Textjoin()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-textjoin-function#:~:text=TEXTJOIN%20is%20a%20new%20function,use%20when%20joining%20text%20values.)

Answer (score 0):

In cell G2, put this:

```
=A2&B2&C2&D2&E2&F2
```

If a separator is needed then add one:

```
=A2&" "&B2&","&C2
```